# To show $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^{\geq 0} \times \mathbb Q^{\geq 0}~:~ mn+1 \mid m^x+n^y \}$ is subset of the lattice $\{\vec u+i \vec v+j \vec w\}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, vector-spaces

I am writing two definitions, the $1$st one is a cover in some sense while the $2$nd one is a lattice:

**Definition 1:** If $m,n$ are integers bigger than $1$, then the set $$A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^{\geq 0} \times \mathbb Q^{\geq 0}~:~ mn+1 \mid m^x+n^y \}$$ is said to be cover of $m$ and $n$.

**Example:** The $5^{th}$ Fermat number is $2^{2^5}+1=641 \times 6700417$. Now $5 \times 2^7+1=641=2^4+5^4$. Therefore \begin{align} &5 \times 2^7+1 \mid 5^4+(2^7)^{4/7} \\
&mn+1 \mid m^x+n^y \end{align} with $m=5,~n=2^7$ and $x=4,~y=4/7$. Thus by definition $(x,y)=(4,4/7)$ covers $(5,2^7)$. Similarly, $(0,2^{5/7})$ belongs to cover of $5$ and $2^7$, because $5 \times 2^7+1$ factors $5^{th}$ Fermat number.

**Definition 2:** Note $\mathbb Q^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Let $\vec u$ is an "arbitrary" vector in $\mathbb Q^2$ and $\{\vec v, \vec w \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb Q^2$. Then the set $$B=\{\vec u+i \vec v+j \vec w~\mid~  i,j \in \mathbb Z\}$$ is a a lattice in $\mathbb Q^2$.

My question-

> I want to show $A \subset B$.

> Or more specifically, if $m$ and $n$ are integers bigger than $1$, then there is a vector $\vec u$ of $\mathbb Q^2$ and a basis $\{v, w\}$ for $\mathbb Q^2$ such that the cover $A$ of $m$ and $n$ is a subset of the lattice $B$ generated by $\vec u$ and $\{v, w\}$.

---

By the above example, $A \ni (4,4/7)=(1,2)+3(1,0)-(0, 10/7)=\vec u+3 \vec v-\vec w \in B$. Note $\{ \vec v, \vec w \}$ forms a basis of $\mathbb Q^2$. Thus, $(4,4/7) \in A \Rightarrow (4,4/7) \in B$. So $A \subset B$ in this case.

Similarly, $A \ni (0,2^{5/7})=(1,-1)+2(-2,2)+(3,11/7) \in B$. Thus $(0,2^{5/7}) \in B$. So $A \subset B$, in this particular case.

General case, take any $(x,y) \in A$. Then since $\{ \vec v, \vec w \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb Q^2$, we can write $(x,y)=a \vec v+b \vec w$ for $a,b \in \mathbb Q$. We don't know whether $a,b$ are integers or not. But we can suitably choose the vector $\vec u \in \mathbb Q^2$ such that $\vec u+a \vec v+b \vec w=(r,s)$ , where $r,s \in \mathbb Z$. Finally, we can "again decompose" $(r,s)$ as $(r,s)=\vec u+i \vec v+j \vec w$ for some suitable $i,j \in \mathbb Z$ and $u,v,w \in \mathbb Q^2$. This implies $(x,y) \in B$.

Thus $A \subset B$.  But I didn't require to use the property of $A$.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Is it $x^m + y^n$ or $m^x + n^y$? Your example seems to be the latter one.

Comment: @SeewooLee, sorry for typo. It is $m^x+n^y$.

Comment: It seems to me that the set $B$ only consists of one element, as $u,v,w,i,j$ are fixed. You certainly don't mean that. Could you please clarify in the notation which item is fixed and which is running? Also, the letters $m,n$ do not show up in the definition of $B$, so there seems to be not connection between the two sets. Or do you mean than the tuple $(m,n)$ should be $(i,j)$?

Comment: @Echo, specifically I mean. if $m$ and $n$ are integers bigger than $1$, then there is a vector $\vec u$ of $\mathbb Q^2$ and a basis $\{v, w\}$ for $\mathbb Q^2$ such that the cover $A$ of $m$ and $n$ is a subset of the lattice $B$ generated by $\vec u$ and $\{v, w\}$.

Comment: The way you have written it, this lattice has only one point.

Comment: @Echo, is it ? In my example, i have shown two points $(4,4/7)$ and $(0,2^{5/7})$ belongs to the lattice $B$. The lattice has more than one point

Comment: No. Read the definition. I believe, what you mean should be $\{ u+iv+jw: i,j\in{\mathbb Z}\}$. What you have written is, that $i,j$ are chosen fixed, and then $B$ is defined.

Comment: @Echo, i didn't fixed$i,j$ but there is one $\vec u$ and a basis $\{u,v\}$. So once we choose $u$, it is fixed, but the $\{u,v\}$ will generate infinitely many points by linear combinations because the scalars $i,j$ can be anything in $\mathbb Z$. So I think the point-lattice $B$ contains infinitely many points in $\mathbb Q^2$. Isn't it?

Comment: Not the way you defined it. Order of quantors.

Comment: @Echo, well, I have rewritten the definition of the lattice $B$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank. Much better. Cheers.